# Executar arquivo sql com SQLiteDatabase Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou implementando em uma Activiy o download de um arquivo sql de um servidor na web. O Download eu já consegui fazer e está funcionando sem problemas. No entanto, ao pegar esse arquivo baixado e mandar executar com o comando execSQL() está matando o aplicativo. Abaixo segue o código que estou usando:

```
private static final String FOLDER ="filedownload";
private static final String FILE_SQL = "file.sql";
private SQLiteDatabase db;
```

**Botão para chamar a classe:**

```
btnExecutar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                int insertCount = insertFromFile();
                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Total de artigos inseridos: " + String.valueOf(insertCount), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

**Classe:**

```
public int insertFromFile() throws IOException {
    int result = 0;

    File file = SecondActivity.this.getFileStreamPath(FOLDER+File.pathSeparator+FILE_SQL);
    FileInputStream insertsStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedReader insertReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(insertsStream));

    while (insertReader.ready()) {
        String insertStmt = insertReader.readLine();
        this.db.execSQL(insertStmt);
        result++;
    }
    insertReader.close();

    return result;
}
```

Está matando o aplicativo, no entanto os registros estão sendo inseridos no banco. O que pode estar errado ou como fazer esse procedimento de forma correta?

**Log do erro**

```
 --------- beginning of crash
04-25 21:55:18.274 1430-1430/myaplication.transition E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
EXCEPTION: main
Process: myaplication.transition, PID: 1430
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:734)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1679)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
    at myaplication.transition.SecondActivity.insertFromFile(SecondActivity.java:178)
    at myaplication.transition.SecondActivity$2.onClick(SecondActivity.java:87)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5640)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22455)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Comment: Qual erro está sendo retornado pra você nas linhas de Log que são exibidas no Android Studio? Pela descrição dele fica mais rápido identificar onde está o problema.

Comment: @LeonardoPaim editei a pergunta e acrescentei o log do erro.

Comment: Tem cara que está dando erro quando tenta executar uma linha vazia. Pode ser a última linha do arquivo (antes do `EOF`) ou uma linha intermediária. Inclua um `if` checando se não está vazia antes de executar o comando.

Comment: @Piovezan não resolveu com o if. Verifiquei o arquivo também e não há linhas vazias.

Comment: Sugiro logar ou dar `println` em cada linha antes de mandar executar, alguma delas está causando o erro. `String.trim()` pode ajudar em algum momento. Se não resolver poste o arquivo para o pessoal tentar reproduzir.

Comment: @Piovezan, você tinha razão! O problema estava no arquivo mesmo. Não havia linhas vazias, no entanto algumas linhas estavam "quebradas" em duas, o que acabava gerando erro de leitura. Ao corrigir isso resolveu o problema. Agradeço a todos!

Comment: Legal que funcionou corretamente. Sugiro agora que poste em forma de resposta a solução que você encontrou. Isso facilita no momento da comunidade buscar soluções.

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar o problema verifiquei no arquivo sql que não haviam linhas vazias, no entanto haviam algumas linhas que estavam "quebradas" em duas, como exemplificado abaixo:

```
INSERT INTO 'tab_status' ('id', 'status', 'descricao') VALUES (1,'Despachado', 
'Arquivo despachado');
```

A solução foi remover essa "quebra" para deixar uma linha única:

```
INSERT INTO 'tab_status' ('id', 'status', 'descricao') VALUES (1,'Despachado', 'Arquivo despachado');
```

Desta forma ao utilizar o while para percorrer as linhas do arquivo sql, o sistema lê a linha  toda, linha a linha, e insere corretamente os dados no banco de dados.